# Mongodb aggregation: get field value using accumulator of another field on the same document

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Say I want to do an aggregation that gets me a set of users where each user is the most recent document inserted with their name.  For example, if I did:

```
db.users.insert({name: 'Bob', _id: 1})
db.users.insert({name: 'Jim', _id: 2})
db.users.insert({name: 'Bob', _id: 3})
```

I would want to get back

```
[
    {name: 'Jim', _id: 2},
    {name: 'Bob', _id: 3}
]
```

This is simple enough - just group by `name` and get `id` as `{$max: '$_id'}`. However, say I introduce a `phoneNumber` field, and I want to also retrieve the `phoneNumber` of 'Jim' and 'Bob'. How can I retrieve this field so that it matches up with the proper id? For example:

```
db.users.insert({name: 'Bob', phone: '555-1234', _id: 1})
db.users.insert({name: 'Jim', phone: '555-5678', _id: 2})
db.users.insert({name: 'Bob', phone: '555-9101', _id: 3})
```

I would want to get back

```
[
    {name: 'Jim', phone: '555-5678', _id: 2},
    {name: 'Bob', phone: '555-9101', _id: 3}
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Solved it:

If you add `{$sort: {_id: -1}}`, you can then use `$first` in the aggregation to get any of the correct fields.